# Is there a way to access SlingRepository in a POJO?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

Is there a way to access `SlingRepository` in a POJO that is not managed by OSGI?

For example, we might have a POJO named `Site`:

```
public class Site {

    private String domainName;

    public String getDomainName() { return domainName; }

    public void setDomainName(String domainName) { this.domainName = domainName; }

    public void validate() throws Exception {
        SlingRepository repo = ...;
        // validation logic dependent on repo
    }
}
```

That is used like this:

```
Site site = new Site();
site.validate();
```

---

### Update (re. Tomek's answer)

The reason why I cannot use `@Reference` or the current request's `ResourceResolver` is because I am trying to implement a JSR-303 (aka Bean validation) validator.

In our Sling app, we have a bunch of servlets that receive JSON payloads from the browser. Then we convert them to pojos:

```
Person p = new Gson().fromJson(json, Person.class)
validate(p); // Validate p using Bean Validation
```

`Person` is a simple POJO annotated with JSR-303 annotations:

```
public class Person {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @UniqueProperty(
      name = "email", 
      path = "/content/myapp", 
      nodeType = "cq:PageContent"
    )
    private String email;

}
```

In short, my goal is to implement the `@UniqueProperty` validation. In the example above, if a node of type `cq:PageContent` under `/content/myapp` exists that has an `email` property with the same value as this model, the validation fails.

The validator class itself will look like this:

```
public class UniquePropertyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueProperty, String {

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueProperty constraintAnnotation) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        // need to execute a JCR query here
    }
}
```

`UniquePropertyValidator` will be instantiated by the JSR-303 implementation (e.g. Hibernate Validator) as needed, and there's no way it can access the current request's resource resolver, hence why I was looking for a way to access the `SlingRepository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should not retrieve external resources from a pojo. Simply add a contructor or setter where you inject the SlingRepository at the position where you do the new. This has the advantage that your pojo is independent of OSGi and can be used in different environments. Also unit testing is easier with this approach.

```
Site site = new Site(slingRepository);
```

Of course this just moves the problem to the class that creates the instance. I guess at some point you start at an activator where you have access to the BundleContext and can lookup the service.

In the rare cases where you really want to lookup a service directly use

```
FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
```

From there you can lookup the service.

Comment: This will make the model dependent on Sling and it is not a good idea IMHO. Think about what would happen if we had to pass a JDBC connection to our POJOs in a JDBC-based program. Or if we had to pass an EntityManager to entities in a Java EE app. Looks backwards to me. I have seen people doing what you've suggested in Sling apps though, and I think they do it only because they have no other choice. I have also updated the post to mention that the POJO is actually a JSR-303 validator and is instantiated by Hibernate Validator and not explicitly by me.

Comment: In your question you indicated that you want to use the SlingRepository inside Site. That is why I showed this in the example. 
In your updated question it seems that you rather need the repository inside the UniquePropertyValidator. As you do not control the lifecycle of this class the FrameworkUtl approach looks like a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you use Sling then using `ResourceResolver` is generally more preferable than `SlingRepository`. It gives you an useful `Resource` abstraction layer and you can still get the underlying JCR `Session` object using `adaptTo()` method.

But back to your question, POJO always lives in a context, there is some entrypoint that runs the whole thing. In Sling there is a few such places: JSP, servlet or an OSGi component. In all of these entrypoints there is at least one way to get access to the repository:

1. JSP

   - use `resourceResolver` binding
   - use `getService(ResourceResolverFactory.class)` to create an administrative resolver,
2. Servlet or filter

   - use `request.getResourceResolver()` to get the request session,
   - or see the next point.
3. Any OSGi service (including servlet or filter)

   - use `@Reference ResourceResolverFactory` to get the factory and create administrative resolver.

After that you can pass the resource resolver to your POJO constructir. I think it's a better option than using hacks with the `FrameworkUtil` for a few reasons:

- if you pass the `ResourceResolver` to the POJO constructor, it's clear that this particular class operates on the repository,
- you don't need to worry about closing sessions (as POJO may not have a defined lifecycle),
- if you create your POJO in servlet or component (cases 1 and 2), it's better to use the request's session to avoid working on the administrative one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tomek. I have updated the question to make it more clear why I need to access `SlingRepository` and I cannot use `ResourceResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian Schneider wrote, you can use this:

```
BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
ServiceReference serviceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(SlingRepository.class);
SlingRepository slingRepository;
if (serviceReference != null) {
   slingRepository = (SlingRepository) bundleContext.getService(serviceReference);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution how you can tap into the lifecycle of the ConstraintValidator.

See:
http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-validationimplementation

Chapter 2.5. The ConstraintValidatorFactory might help you. If you register a ConstraintValidatorFactory in e.g. your Activator then you can supply it with the SlingRepository. The factory can then forward the SlingRepository to the Validator it creates. So you can keep the OSGi logic out of the Validator.